# How to keep track of the running video element in a dynamic website using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the next code as a browser extension to detect the video element of a page and to seek forward and backward through it using the buttons.
It works on most website even YouTube shorts.
but when I tried to use it on Instagram to only control the first video even if you run another video or reel.

```
// Create the seek forward button
const seekForwardButton = document.createElement('button');
seekForwardButton.textContent = '➡';
seekForwardButton.classList.add('seek-for-button');
seekForwardButton.classList.add('seek-button');

// Create the seek backward button
const seekBackwardButton = document.createElement('button');
seekBackwardButton.textContent = '⬅';
seekBackwardButton.classList.add('seek-back-button');
seekBackwardButton.classList.add('seek-button');


// Add event listeners to the buttons
seekForwardButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const videoElement = document.querySelector('video');
  if (videoElement) {
    videoElement.currentTime += 3;
  }
});

seekBackwardButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const videoElement = document.querySelector('video');
  if (videoElement) {
    videoElement.currentTime += -3;
  }
});

// Append the buttons to the document body
document.body.appendChild(seekForwardButton);
document.body.appendChild(seekBackwardButton);
```

I tried multple ways including (detect the running element every x seconds and then add the control to it, using a thrid button that when pressed to detect the video element) but none worked.

Does someone has any ideas how to make it work?